# Extending the document structure hierarchy for a report

Tags: sectioning

For a 11 pt. report document class which I am using for my thesis, I can only get the following heading levels on a per chapter basis:

```
\chapter

\section

\subsection

\subsubsection
```

I am not including the paragraph sections above, as they do not pertain to headings.

My question is: is there a way to extend the above limited hierarchy to include more heading levels? Alternatively, is there a package which provides such an extension?

For example in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{This is a part}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\subsubsection{This is a subsubsection}
\paragraph{This is a paragraph}
\subparagraph{This is a subparagraph}
\end{document}
```

There is no numbering generated for the paragraph or the subparagraph....so these would not be captured in TOC. I need to create a numbered hierarchy with more depth than that allowed by above. My actual need is to have another level above the \section{} to form a generic heading for the discussion that follows in the section and the subsections. Is there a way to do this in such a way that it is sequentially numbered automatically, and captured in TOC as well?

TIA

Vinod

Comment: Please make the question more clear. all standard class (report is one) have 7 levels (part, ..., subparagraph) may be you need to change `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}`.

Comment: @touhami: You mean to increase the `secnumdepth` counter to `5` or `6`

Comment: sections are numbered to `secnumdepth` so set `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}` if you want level 5 sections numbered, similary set  `\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}` if you want all levels in the toc

Comment: The extra question added about a level between chapter and section is probably best asked as a new question and isn't really clear without an example, how do you want numbering to work?

Comment: you can try `titlesec` http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/titlesec/titlesec.pdf#page=9

Answer (score 2):

The next heading levels are `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` they *do* pertain to headings they are defined using `\@startsection` almost exactly the same as `\section`, but at levels 4 and 5.

The source of these commands in `report.cls` is below:

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{This is a part}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\subsubsection{This is a subsubsection}
\paragraph{This is a paragraph}
\subparagraph{This is a subparagraph}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Let me explain what I implied with a MWE....I have edited my original post

Comment: @Vinod Christian addressed that point in his comment some hours ago, I just repeated it in a comment under the question.

Comment: @Vinod I added an image of the output from your MWE

Comment: @ David Carlisle thanks....I will try and work with your example....